# Unknown requests made to apache

Tags: apache

I have noticed today that someone was trying to access my apache to get the content form external site's  which I don't have any idea and looks strange.

Can someone help to make config change on my apache to avoid this to happening?

I don't have mod-proxy enabled on my apache configuration

```
- - [30/Jan/2015:02:33:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 18335 "http://opzionibinarietecniche.com:81/gate/big5/www.fwcityvision.org/stats/referrer.html" 
- - [30/Jan/2015:03:37:43 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 18335 "//amazon.gewinnen.pw:81/gate/big5/www.fwcityvision.org/stats/referrer.html"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is just the referrer field which tells you from where your user came.  I don't believe they are trying to access those sites from your site.

It may be a bot of some sort indexing your site for a search engine.

http://fwcityvision.org/ seems to be some Washington state city resource tool.  Could it be something that you signed up for?

If not, you could investigate blocking them based on the referrer.  Here is a good resource on how to do that.

https://www.addedbytes.com/blog/block-referrer-spam/

Thanks